# how many equivalance classes are in the function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

My Discrete Math textbook has this example of a function:
There's a set $A=\text{{1,2,3}}$. Also: $f: P(A) \to P(A)$. The function is defined as follows:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
A-x;x\cap\{3\}\neq\emptyset\\
x\cup\{3\};x\cap\{3\}=\emptyset\\
\end{cases}$$
Lastly we set a relation $R=A\times A$ based on the function we defined above:
$$xRy \iff f(x)=f(y)$$
The textbook then asks if the relation is an equivalence relation and if yes then how many equivalence classes there are. The answer is that yes it's an equivalence relation and there're 8 classes. Can you please help understand why? The way I see it let's take for example: $f(\{1\})=\{1,3\}$ while $ f(\{1,3\})=\{2\}$. In this example $f(x)\neq f(y)$ so $xRy$ is not (part of) the relation because it doesn't conform to the conditions. Same goes for all other members of the set.

Comment: Homework: Prove that for ANY function $f: X \to Y$, where $X,Y$ are ANY sets, the relation $R \subseteq X \times X$ defined by $$xRx' \Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(x')$$ is always an equivalence relation.

Comment: @Crostul: Presumably the OP's question goes partway toward understanding that.

Comment: @BrianTung You are right, but he is trying to prove this using the particular properties of this particular $f$, while I'm trying to make him understand deeply this concept.

Comment: @Crostul: Not everyone learns the specific case better by attempting the general rule first.  In this case, I think the obstacle may be understanding what $xRy \leftrightarrow f(x) = f(y)$ means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $f$ is injective. $\phantom{yadayadayada}$.

---

Edit: I'll give some more details on how to solve this problem.

Let's show that $R$ is transitive: Suppose $x,y,z\in P(A)$ satisfying $xRy$ and $yRz$. We need to show that $xRz$.

By definition of $R$, $xRy$ means that $f(x)=f(y)$, and from $yRz$ we obtain $f(y)=f(z)$. Therefore, $f(x)=f(y)=f(z)$, which in turn implies $xRz$ as we wanted. Therefore $R$ is transitive. (If you think this is too pedantic, you can probably write a slicker version.)

Reflexivity and symmetry of $R$ are proved similarly, and I'll leave that to you.

As for the equivalence classes, you have to answer the question: "given $x\in P(A)$, what are the elements $y\in P(A)$ for which $xRy$?". The equivalence class of $x$ is then $R(x)=\left\{y\in P(A): xRy\right\}$. The number of equivalence classes is the number of distinct sets of the form $R(x)$, for $x\in P(A)$.

Comment: f(x) is indeed injective as well as surjective. But I don't see how f(x)=f(y)

Comment: @Yos Then $f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y$, so $R$ is equality.

Comment: I think I got you. Because $f(x)$ is injective in the first place so $f(x)=f(y)$. Ok, so now I do see why $xRy$ belongs to the relation. But why is it an equivalence relation? For example, the pair $\{1,3\}R\{2\}$ on its own how is it equivalence relation? Doesn't it need to be like this for this: {1,3}R{2}, {2}R{1,3}, {1,3}R{1,3} because equivalence relation must be reflexive, symmetric and transitive?

Comment: @Yos: No.  $\{1, 3\}R\{2\}$ is not correct, because $f(\{1, 3\}) \not= f(\{2\})$.  The only time $xRy$ is correct is when $x = y$; the equivalence relation is equality itself.

Comment: @Yos: I think you are confusing $xRy$ with $f(x) = y$.  What the question says is: $xRy$ if and only if $f(x) = f(y)$.

Comment: So would this examle be  a correct one: $f({1})=f({1})$ where {1} is a subset of P(A)?

Comment: @Yos You seem extremely confused about the definition of equivalence relation and the goal of the problem. You need, essentially, to "follow a recipe": First, verify that $R$ is an equivalence relation on the set $P(A)$ (**not on $A$**), that is, verify that the [axioms of an equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Definition) are satisfied. Second, recall the [definition of equivalence class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Equivalence_class). Try to calculate them with the $R$ you are given, Show that there are $8$ with my and Brian's hints

Comment: thanks for your help. I know that equivalence relation needs to be reflexive, symmetric and transitive. It would really help my understand if you could provide an example of a part of the relation that we would get. I think once I can actually see it I will understand.

Comment: @Yos I added a few more comments. Hope everything is clear now.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro: +1.  Hopefully!

Comment: @LuizCordeiro thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Note that ${\cal P}(A) = 2^3 = 8$, so each subset is on its own.  There are no subsets $x \not= y$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$, but that doesn't mean it's not an equivalence relation.

---

ETA: We may need to go a little more basic here.  First, what are the elements of ${\cal P}(A)$?  They are:

$$
\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\}
$$

The function $f$ maps each of those sets into another set; respectively, they are

$$
\{3\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 2, 3\}, \{2\}, \{1\}, \emptyset
$$

The definition of the relation $R$ says that $xRy$ whenever $f(x) = f(y)$.  So let's suppose, just for example, that $x = \{1, 3\}$.  Then $f(x) = \{2\}$.  We ask ourselves, is there any $y$ such that $f(y)$ also equals $\{2\}$?  We find that the only such $y$ is $x = \{1, 3\}$ itself.  That is,

$$
\{1, 3\}Ry
$$

only when $y = x = \{1, 3\}$ and for no other choice of $y$.

If we go through this exercise for all eight possible choices of $x$ (left to the reader), we find that this is true for all $x$: The only $y$ such that $f(y) = x$ is that $x$ itself.  (This is because there are no two elements of ${\cal P}(A)$ that map to the same result.)

Is this an equivalence relation?  Well, do we have $xRx$?  Yes, if you go through the above exercise, you verify that.  And is it the case that $xRy$ whenever $yRx$?  You should be able to convince yourself that that is true, too, since the only relations are of the form $xRx$ anyway.  And finally, if $xRy$ and $yRz$, is it also the case that $xRz$?  Yes, for the same reason: we only have relations of the form $xRx$.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you please give one example of such a set?

Comment: Of what kind of set?  I didn't mention any sets.  I'm saying every subset of $A$ is its own equivalence class, because for every distinct $x, y$, we have $f(x) \not= f(y)$.

Comment: So is Luiz Cordeiro, for that matter.

Comment: @Yos: I've added some more detail here.  Hopefully between Luiz's answer and mine (and Crostul's comment), you will understand.

Comment: Thank you so much @BrianTung I know truly understand! I didn't realize what they implied by $f(x)=f(y)$.